# Using two environment variables to block access in Apache .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, environment-variables, mod-access

I'm using SetEnvIf and Deny to block access to certain countries in my .htaccess.

But I need to exclude certain URLs from this blocking, and thus I'm setting another environment variable for those URLs.

How do I Deny based on a combination of variable 1 and variable 2 ?

```
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE xx BlockedCountry
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/important" NeverBlock
```

In pseudo code I want to do this now:

```
Deny from env=BlockedCountry && !NeverBlock
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Apache documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#deny) :

> Syntax:   Deny from all|host|env=[!]env-variable
>   [host|env=[!]env-variable] ...

Which means you can combine conditions one after the other (there is no "boolean" operators in between).

So in your case, it should look like this

```
Deny from env=BlockedCountry env=!NeverBlock
```

## Update

From what you said, it looks like this implies an `OR` condition instead of an `AND` (what you want). To do so, you can use this workaround

```
SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE xx MustBeBlocked
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/important" !MustBeBlocked

Deny from env=MustBeBlocked
```

With this technique, you set/unset the environment variable depending on the case, which simulates an `AND` condition.

Comment: Thanks for the reference, but there seems to be an implied OR between the 2 conditions. Now access is denied when its a bad country OR a URL that doesn't fall in the 'never block' category. Thats too much. I need an AND for the conditions.

Comment: This works in this short example, but is there a gurantee that Apache processes the directives in the order that they appear in the config ? I really would have preferred to use 2 variables.

Comment: My guess would be that each line is evaluated sequentially. Maybe you can find an answer in the Apache documentation. Another solution would be to use `mod_rewrite` (along with `mod_geoip`) and in this case each condition is evaluated in order of appearance.